# multicolumn table in Beamer

Tags: tables, multicolumn, beamer

I'm new to beamer. I want to have table in my presentation same as in my latex document.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Condition (Gold standard)}\\
\cline{3-4}
& & True & False \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{Test outcome}}& \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Positive} & True Positive \cellcolor{green} & False Positive\cellcolor{red}\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Negative} & False Negative\cellcolor{red} & True Negative \cellcolor{green}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This is the table, but the multicolumn command is not working in beamer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. It's also helpful to post a complete minimal document rather than just a fragment.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the `[table]` option to `beamer` (which will then pass it to the `xcolor` package, which it loads).

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Condition (Gold standard)}\\
\cline{3-4}
& & True & False \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{Test outcome}}& 
  \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Positive} & True Positive \cellcolor{green} & 
  False Positive\cellcolor{red}\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Negative} & 
  False Negative\cellcolor{red} & True Negative \cellcolor{green}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]